# Whats the quickest way to echo out a value in a multi dimension array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 0
                [Name] => Joe
                [Frags] => 0
                [Time] => 443603
                [TimeF] => 03:13:23
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 0
                [Name] => Bob 
                [Frags] => 0
                [Time] => 439364
                [TimeF] => 02:02:44
            )
    )
```

I want to echo out the name Joe and Bob, so for each array inside this array, I want to echo just the name.

I can't figure the best way to do this?

Comment: `foreach` over `array_column`

Comment: You can test this without asking here and you can also research this on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, your array is stored in the variable `$array`:

```php
foreach ($array as $entry) {
  echo $entry['Name'] . '<br />';
}
```

More about [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) in the PHP docs.